# dropping dataframe indexes based on boolean of series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'country': ['USA','Italy','France'], 'Jan':[-150,2,50], 'Feb':[100,0.5,2],'Mar':[200,0,5]})
df.set_index('country', inplace=True)
```

I would like to drop any index which does not contain any value greater than 10 in absolute value - in this case, "Italy".

I can check this condition for a given index as follows:

```
(df.loc['Italy'].abs()>10).any()
```

Is there an efficient way to apply this logic to every index in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Check with `any`

```
df.abs().gt(10).any(1)
country
USA        True
Italy     False
France     True
dtype: bool
```